# Is it possible for a PWA app to upload image/video files when app is in background on IOS?

Tags: safari, background, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, uploading

I have a PWA app which allow user to upload video/image file to server side, and user may use the app from phone's browser. However, the app can have many chance to go to the background, for example, if the uploading takes long enough, the phone may locked after certain time of in-active, or user may switch to other app while they waiting for the uploading to finish.

I know the service worker background fetch/sync api would be an option for Android device, but those are marked as not supported by iOS Safari.

Does anyone know if it is possible for PWA app which launch from Safari of an iphone to continue uploading when it is in background?

Thanks!

I know the service worker background fetch/sync api would be an option for Android device, but those are marked as not supported by iOS Safari. I hope there is a way or workaround for iOS to work.

Comment: how can you do it on android? do you have a link to mozila docs?